# Using MVVM Light, ViewModelLocator hold all ViewModels?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, mvvm-light

I'm using MVVM Light.

This is my scenario:

I want to add one or more student through a window, and there are two ways to achieve this. 
The first is to list all students(displaying UserControl1), and the other is to manually input the student's name (displaying UserControl2).

The `Window` consist of a `ContentControl` (which is one of two `UserControl`s) and some `Button`s on the bottom.

[image]

The Window and two different UserControl corresponds 3 different Viewmodels(AddStudentsViewModel, AutoScanStudentsViewModel and ManuallyAddStudentViewModel).

I'm new to MVVM, so I can't determine if **to put 3 ViewModels all in ViewModelLocator or put the 2 latter ViewModels in AddStudentsViewModel?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the specific example that you have given, I would expose the latter 2 ViewModels as properties of the AddStudentsViewModel.

However, if it was valid for the latter 2 ViewModels to be shown on their own, i.e. in a PopupWindow, there would be no reason why you couldn't add them to your ViewModelLocator as well.